# Split python array into equally-sized chunks and omit elements at indexes

Tags: python, arrays, split, slice, chunks

I need to iterate indexes from e.g. 0-6, 30-36, 60-66 etc and omit the values at indexes in between.

I found sth like this for splitting into equal chunks but did not find a way to exclude specific indexes...

```
def chunks(xs, n):
n = max(1, n)
return (xs[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(xs), n))
```

Does anyone has a hint?

Thanks and all the best

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to

```
def chunks(xs, n):
    steps = 30 # you should also give the steps in your case it is 30
    n = max(1, n)
    return (xs[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(xs), steps))  # Also this will be returning generator if you want list then use [xs[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(xs), steps)]
```